# Cannot resolve symbol 'jakarta'

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am using the latest version of the hibernate validator package in my maven project.  My pom file contains this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.4.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When I use version 6, everything works fine, but with version 7, the following method throws an error.

```
private void addValidationError(ConstraintViolation<?> cv) {
    this.addValidationError(
            cv.getRootBeanClass().getSimpleName(),
            ((PathImpl) cv.getPropertyPath()).getLeafNode().asString(),
            cv.getInvalidValue(),
            cv.getMessage());
}
```

The error is with the cast to PathImpl.  Hovering over the error I get this message:

```
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'javax.validation.Path' to 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.path.PathImpl'
```

When I navigate to the PathImpl class, I can see that the file (in the jar that has been automatically downloaded and is of course not controlled by me) does not compile because these two lines in it are erroring

```
import jakarta.validation.ElementKind;
import jakarta.validation.Path;
```

The error is

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'jakarta'
```

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

My POM file is below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.x</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-api</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>my-api</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <springfox-version>3.0.0</springfox-version>
        <serenity-version>3.1.15</serenity-version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.8</version>
    </parent>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.15</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--SpringFox dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-oas</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.joschi.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dev -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.4.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Security-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bean Validation API support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kohsuke/github-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.slack.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>bolt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opsgenie.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdk</artifactId>
            <version>[2.0.0,)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datadoghq</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-dogstatsd-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.17.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.202203080745-r</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.fabianlinz</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.260</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mix Java EE with Jakarta EE.

With the most recent version the namespaces have changed from javax to jakarta.

Make sure that your dependencies are all up to date and use the same version.

**Important notice**

You are using Spring Boot. And Spring Boot will be ready for Jakarta EE with version 3!
So you cannot use any dependency that is using something from the jakarta namespace.

Additionally with Spring Boot you shouldn't override the version that comes with it.

Comment: The only thing in my pom file that mentions javax is this.  I will try and change this: <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: I changed this to this, with no luck <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Can you please show your pom.xml?

Comment: I've edited the question and posted my entire pom file.

Comment: Answer accepted.  I have other similar errors too so may ask you about those as well. - thank you - you know a lot about this stuff.  I'm a .NET guy so know less about this stuff.  It's strange that version 3 isn't even out yet.

Comment: It's a lot of work for the Spring Team to migrate to new Jakarta EE. So this takes a while. Beside of that there are many other improvements and features added.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of namespace changing from `javax` to `jakarta` in newer versions of Jakarta EE specifications. You should use older version of hibernate-validator (as you said) or just update *Jakarta platform* dependency as for compatibility:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I added this to my pom file but I still get the sam error?

Comment: @SachinKainth What's your webserver? and the version?

Comment: <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.8</version>
    </parent>

Comment: I've edited my question and posted my entire pom file.

Comment: @SachinKainth This error is because of internal incompatibility of your Spring boot dependencies. Managing dependencies in this manner is difficult. Just use [spring-boot-starter-validation] (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/2.7.1) instead of adding the dependency (hibernate-validator) manually and change your code depend on it. Spring boot starter validation is updated to hibernate-validator version 7.0.4.Final as you want.